# Nonlinear completely continuous operators and uniformly continuous operators on bounded sets

Tags: functional-analysis

This a refinement of a question that I recently asked.

Suppose T : X -> Y is a nonlinear nondecreasing and completely continuous operator, where X and Y are real Banach spaces, and X is reflexive. Is it true that T is a uniformly continuous operator on bounded sets?

Thanks! Uriel

Comment: What does "nondecreasing" mean in this context?

Comment: If $u\leq v$, then $Tu\leq Tv$. Maybe I should have put ordered Banach spaces. ;) I am thinking of X and Y being function spaces, and $T$ being a solution operator of a boundary value problem.

Comment: I don't think the order helps here since it has nothing to do with topology. Or has it? I think the claim is false.

Comment: Sometimes monotone operators have good properties. In any case, I also think it is false, despite hoping it is true.